# Camel Netty4 detects deadlock on reconnect

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I have an issue getting re-connect with camel-netty/netty4 working. Reconnect is triggered successfully when connection gets lost. But the attempt to reconnect fails with netty detecting a potential deadlock (see stacktrace below). After that exception, no further reconnect attempts are made.

Is this a netty/camel bug or did I miss anything?

```
2017-02-27 18:23:18,076  WARN | Camel Thread #33 - NettyServerTCPWorker | o.a.c.c.netty4.ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory | Error during re-connect to x.x.x.x:yyyy. Will attempt again in 2000 millis. This exception is ignored. 
io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@3fde00eb(incomplete)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:390)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultChannelPromise.java:157)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:283)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelPromise.java:135)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
       at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.openChannel(ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:175)
       at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.doReconnectIfNeeded(ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:164)
       at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory$2.run(ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:216)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tested with camel 2.16.2 and 2.18.1 using netty 4.0.33.Final and 4.0.41.Final, respectively.

**EDIT:**

I've just verified that this only happens if `workerCount=1` is set. Is this intended?